# How to grab the first item in the array after using split

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code.  I am trying to grab the first element in the array after the split.  After the split the first alert returns '2012, 0' and the second alert returns '0'.  I want to grab the '2012'.  Does anyone know how I would do that?

```
    var today = new Date();     
    var currentYear = today.getUTCFullYear();       
    var ratingsData = [];
    var ratingsArray= [];
    var ratings = iGetElementsByClassName("empRatings", document, "DIV");

for (x=0; x<ratings.length; x++){
        ratingsData[x] = ratings[x].innerHTML.split("/");
        ratingsArray[x] = ratingsData[x][1];

alert(ratingsData[x]);
alert(ratingsArray[x]);
```

Comment: how does criticizing how I defined my variables at all help me figure out this solution?  and that is purely a matter of opinion

Comment: _"There are 2 hard problems in computer science: caching, naming, and off-by-one errors"_ -- it's a joke but not untrue.

Comment: that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are zero indexed, use zero to get the first item:

```
ratingsArray[x] = ratingsData[x][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

"split" returns an array, and you store the entire array in a single variable, then show this array in its entirety.

Use this instead:

```
alert(ratingsData[x][0]);
```

-- it only shows the first value in the returned array.